# Python "protected" attributes

Tags: python

How do I access a private attribute of a parent class from a subclass (without making it public)?

Comment: Do you mean protected, or private? Your question is different from your title ...

Comment: Since protected and private don't mean much in Python, please provide actual code.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

My understanding of Python convention is

- _member is protected
- __member is private

Options for if you control the parent class

- Make it protected instead of private
  since that seems like what you really
  want
- Use a getter (@property def
  _protected_access_to_member...) to limit the protected access

If you don't control it

- Undo the name mangling.  If you
  dir(object) you will see names
  something like _Class__member which is
  what Python does to leading __ to
  "make it private".  There isn't
  truly private in python.  This is probably considered evil.

Comment: Important note: the purpose of the `__` prefix is not to make the attribute private in a *visibility* sense but in an *inheritance* sense, mostly in order to avoid naming conflicts when a class is designed specifically for inheritance. As the comment notes, the mangling scheme is well defined and stable, so it won't stop anyone from accessing the attribute (or updating it) if they really want to.

Answer (score 64):

## Two philosophies of protection

Some language designers subscribe to the following assumption:

> *"Many programmers are irresponsible, dim-witted, or both."*

These language designers will feel tempted to protect programmers from each other by introducing a `private` specifier into their language.
Shortly later they recognize that this is often too inflexible and introduce `protected` as well.

Language designers such as Python's Guido van Rossum, in contrast, assume that programmers are responsible adults and capable of good judgment (perhaps not always, but typically).
They find that everybody should be able to access the elements of a program if there is a need to do that, so that the language does not get in the way of doing the right thing.
(The only programming language that can reliably get in the way of doing the *wrong* thing is the [NULL](http://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/new90/nullang.html) language)

Therefore, `_myfield` in Python means something like "The designer of this module is doing some non-obvious stuff with this attribute, so please do not modify it and stay away from even reading it if you can -- suitable ways to access relevant information have been provided (or so we hope)."

In case you are not able to stay away from accessing `_myfield` (such as in special cases in a subclass), you simply access it.

Comment: Can you believe it @san, the analogy has [already been made](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2011/02/16/if-programming-languages-were-religions/)?

Answer (score 18):

Using `@property` and `@name.setter`   to do what you want

e.g

```
class Stock(object):

    def __init__(self, stockName):

        # '_' is just a convention and does nothing
        self.__stockName  = stockName   # private now


    @property # when you do Stock.name, it will call this function
    def name(self):
        return self.__stockName

    @name.setter # when you do Stock.name = x, it will call this function
    def name(self, name):
        self.__stockName = name

if __name__ == "__main__":
      myStock = Stock("stock111")

      myStock.__stockName  # It is private. You can't access it.

      #Now you can myStock.name
      N = float(raw_input("input to your stock: " + str(myStock.name)+" ? "))
```

Comment: The question was about accessing the attribute in a subclass.

Comment: I modified your example a little bit.  See below.

Answer (score 14):

No one seems to answer the original question

> how to access a private attribute of a parent class from a subclass

So here's a simple use case, demonstrating two options - accessing parent class [__private variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) and using [@property decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Family:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__family_name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__family_name


class Child(Family):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        super(Child, self).__init__(last_name)
        self.__child_name = first_name


    @property
    def name(self):
        return (self.__child_name, super(Child, self).name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_child = Child("Albert", "Einstein")

    # print (my_child.__child_name)         # AttributeError - trying to access private attribute '__child_name'
    # print (my_child.__family_name)        # AttributeError - trying to access private attribute '__family_name'
    print (my_child._Child__child_name)     # Prints "Albert" - By accessing __child_name of Child sub-class
    print (my_child._Family__family_name)   # Prints "Einstein" - By accessing __family_name in Family super-class
    print (" ".join(my_child.name))         # Prints "Albert Einstein" - By using @property decorators in Child and Family
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the actual question instead of using the question as a pulpit. For anyone else landing here, the bit in the docs that explains this is @ https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables, specifically the "name mangling" bit. Noam's answer explained it well, but I dug out the docs cos I wanted to read the official wording on it too. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

if the variable name is "__secret" and the class name is "MyClass" you can access it like this on an instance named "var"

var._MyClass__secret

The convention to suggest/emulate protection is to name it with a leading underscore: self._protected_variable = 10

Of course, anybody can modify it if it really wants.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code is a little clearer than Steve's.  Steve's answer was most helpful for what I am trying to do, so thank you!  I tested this with python 2.7 and python 3.6.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#
# From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797771/python-protected-attributes
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

class Stock(object):

    def __init__(self, stockName):

        # '_' is just a convention and does nothing
        self.__stockName  = stockName   # private now


    @property # when you do Stock.name, it will call this function
    def name(self):
        print("In the getter, __stockName is %s" % self.__stockName, file=sys.stderr)
        return self.__stockName

    @name.setter # when you do Stock.name = x, it will call this function
    def name(self, name):
        print("In the setter, name is %s will become %s" % ( self.__stockName, name), file=sys.stderr)
        self.__stockName = name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myStock = Stock("stock111")

    try:
        myStock.__stockName  # It is private. You can't access it.
    except AttributeError as a:
        print("As expect, raised AttributeError", str(a), file=sys.stderr )
    else:
        print("myStock.__stockName did did *not* raise an AttributeError exception")


    #Now you can myStock.name
    myStock.name = "Murphy"
    N = float(input("input to your stock: " + str(myStock.name)+" ? "))
    print("The value of %s is %s" % (myStock.name, N) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an accessor method, unless I am missing something:

```
def get_private_attrib(self):
  return self.__privateWhatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Code modified from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/protected-variable-in-python/#:%7E:text=Protected%20variables%20are%20those%20data,data%20member%20in%20a%20class.)

```
# program to illustrate protected
# data members in a class 
  
  
# Defining a class
class Geek: 
    # private
    __name = "R2J"
    # protected data members 
    _roll = 1706256
    def __init__(self, value):
        value1 = value
        self.value2 = value
    # public member function 
    def displayNameAndRoll(self): 
  
        # accessing protected data members 
        print("Name: ", self.__name) 
        print("Roll: ", self._roll) 
  
  
# creating objects of the class         
obj = Geek(1)
obj.__name = 'abc'
obj._roll = 12345

# calling public member 
# functions of the class 
obj.displayNameAndRoll()
```

Note that I can modifies without setter the protected attribute, but not the private.

```
Name:  R2J
Roll:  12345
```

OBS: running in python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

There is a process of name mangling when you instantiate a non public attribute. In order to access the attribute outside of the class you need to "un-mangle".

Example:
Class creation

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

Create instance:

```
obj = Object('test')
```

Access non public attribute (un-mangle):

```
print(obj._Object__name)
```