# Override property of class inheritting

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, overriding

Trying to override an attribute from an inherrited class what is the proper way to do it? Both of following example do not work :( seems intuitive for me like that
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

```
class Mamal(object):

    __name = 'Mamal'

    def out(self):
        print (self.__name)

class Person(Mamal):

    __name = 'Person attribute overriden'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = 'Person from init'

class Test:

    def test(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        l_pers = Person()
        l_pers.out() # Gives Mamal


t = Test()
t.test()
```

Comment: First there is already an attribute `__name__` so you don't need to create one, and it should also be `__init__` not `__init` so it is not actually called and your attribute is not overriden. Lastly, apart from a few Syntax Errors, this is not reproducible as there is no calling code here...

Comment: sorry, didn't try my example, I'll rewrite it after trying it

Comment: Don't know if you are using private attributes on purpose, but if you are see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797771/python-protected-attributes). If not, just change `__name` to `name`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Great!! You gave me the answer! would you like to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: which is that? The link or the `name`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo replacing `__name` by `_name` with single `_` as protected attribute did the trick, as the private attributes are private and not available to child class as you pointed out with the link

Comment: In that case I think it should just be a duplicate, because your answer is there so no point in posting another

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes it does, but I'd answer the specific question so that its quicker for others to find the answer